# WKWebView media controls title displays Url

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api, swift4, wkwebview

Is it possible to change the iOS media controls (lock screen, command center media) title from the Url when playing a video from **WKWebView**?

I have tryied the following and cannot get Now Playing info to change:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    var nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "Some title"
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
}
```

Using https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api **onYouTubeIframeAPIReady** I can get the title and send it back to the app, but the issue is getting the now applying controls to update the title from the video Url.

Comment: Hey! Did you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I never found a way, so I think it's not possible in the SDK currently. Best would be to file a radar with Apple requesting this.

Answer (score 0):

The MPNowPlayingInfoCenter displays the title of the webpage as title of the currently played audio/video.
Since the homepage title is never visible in the webview, you can freely change it via Javascript as soon as a new audio or video file is played:

```
document.title = "your title";
```

The new homepage title will now be displayed on your NowPlayingInfoCenter as currently playing audio/video.
Works great for me.

You could also do it inside the app code (Objective-C):

```
[webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.title = \"your title\";" completionHandler:nil];
```